# if(isnumber) with multiple cells

Tags: excel-formula

I am using the following logic function `=IF(ISNUMBER(B5),B5*B2,"")` which works great but what I need is if `B5` is blank the formula must go on and check `C5` for a number to be multiplied similarly. I realise the following formula has too many arguments but hopefully someone out there can steer me in the correct direction.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B5),B5*B2,(ISNUMBER(C5,C5*B2,""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's an embedded if function

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B5),B5*B2,IF(ISNUMBER(C5),C5*B2,IF(ISNUMBER(D5),D5*B2,"")))
```